# It's getting harder and harder for my friends to like me

Tags: riddle, number-sequence, algorithm

**What is the next number in this sequence?**

> 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 18, 25, 27, 54, 73, 97, 129, 171, 231, 313, 327, 649, 703, ... ?

Hint 1

> Examine each number for 2's. It's
>  Ok to play by the rules, But
>  See that it's fun for 71, and please
>  Deny high 5's to fools

Hint 2

> There's no proof to be done
>  You can't hit a home run
>  You're weird, so just take a triple
>  Maybe one more
>  Til you hit the floor
>  Call it, for friendshipz, a cripple.

*This is my first puzzle and I'm new to PSE, so feedback is much appreciated!*

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! As a heads-up, it's preferred that you hold off from including hints until about a day or so after you posted the question. On the other hand, this looks like an original, high-quality number-sequence puzzle, and those are a rarity here IMO. Feel free to take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site.

Comment: That said, if you go asking people questions like this, you'll get a warmer reception on PSE than amongst your current friends, so welcome onboard!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are

> new maxima-so-far of the "how many steps of the Collatz iteration to 1?" function

and the next one is

> 871 (which takes 178 steps, versus the previous record of 170 steps starting from 703).

By way of clarification:

> If we start at 2, we get [2,1]: one step. If we start at 3, we get [3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]: 7 steps, a new record. 4 goes [4,2,1], fewer than 3, so it isn't in the list. 5 goes [5,16,8,4,2,1], again no improvement. 6 goes to 3 and then follows 3's path: 8 steps, a new record. So our sequence begins 2,3,6. (Arguably it should really go 1,2,3,6.)

Comment: dang, I guess riddle hints were not necessary at all.  good to know for next time!

Comment: No, the hints were extremely helpful and I don't think I'd have solved it without them.

Comment: (In particular, the "take a triple / maybe one more" lines were ... quite informative.)